# Description of Editing and Rep and FAQ

Tags: discussion, editing

Seems like this question should have been asked already but I can't find any details.

I'm looking for a description of Editing (beyond Jeff's seminal article, [In Defense of Editing](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/). Specifically, I'm looking for answers to questions like:

- Who verifies the edits and when?
- How do we get to where our edits are no longer verified each time?
- What rep do we need to not have our edits always verified?
- What would our edits be rejected for?
- How do we know whether our edit was rejected or not?
- How do we see what our edits have been?
- *Perhaps most importantly!* Where do I find the answers to these questions?

There doesn't seem to be anything in the ServerFault FAQ (where I started) nor in the Metafault "FAQ" (which appears to have only four questions in it).

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that those with sufficient rep can just edit to their heart's content but there's nothing stopping someone else with enough rep from either rolling back the edit or editing it again. Just sometimes this can turn into a bit of an editing war.

Comment: I know about edit wars (though I've been spared experiencing one thankfully). Over at Wikipedia [I'm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:DavidDouthitt) a [Wikifærie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiFairy) (a/k/a copyeditor). But others may not know about [edit wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_wars).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [this post on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) that explains suggested edits in detail and should answer all your questions.

Whether it should be added to the site FAQ is something to consider.

Comment: Even though someone else actually answered the questions... this is the _best_ answer! Thanks! I hope that question becomes a FAQ, as it really should.

Answer (score 2):

```
Who verifies the edits and when?
```

Users on this site over 5,000 rep.

```
How do we get to where our edits are no longer verified each time?
```

You have to have over 2,000 rep.

```
What rep do we need to not have our edits always verified?
```

To edit *any post* without the suggestion system you need 20,000.

```
What would our edits be rejected for?
```

It gives a reason in the rejection, but it's almost always:

- Too minor, like fixing a single word typo or two
- Changes the meaning, especially adding content the OP did not intend

These get subjective sometimes; and some reviewers are more lenient than others.

```
How do we know whether our edit was rejected or not?
```

On your account screen, activities tab, suggestions sub-tab... says there

```
How do we see what our edits have been?
```

You can see the suggestions from the above, and see the post history within each of those links.

```
Perhaps most importantly! Where do I find the answers to these questions?
```

They're scattered... We're not always the most organized.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/155320) at M.SO which gives an overview of "How does editing work?".

Granted, the FaQ does sometimes seem a bit light on detail and sometimes would benefit to a link to the community wiki'd answers and questions mentioned above.